# Wordpress Walker class seems to make items "invisible"

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

so im tryin to put my BS (ver 3.2) over my WP (ver 4 or the latest cant recall), and I followed some guides online.
I ran into the "Walker" class etc. but i just cant get it right.
the list items

and their tags will show up, but the links themselves wont.
Here's the link for my Functions.php file:

```
http://pastebin.com/AMaHgvkh
```

and here's the link for my header.php

```
http://pastebin.com/z4gGU43V
```

and here's the walker file (which i took from the GIT so nothing special here)

```
http://pastebin.com/0wP8UE47
```

Can anyone help me with this walker issue?
doesnt matter what i try i just dont get it right...

Thanks !

Comment: can you please paste the html that is generated?

Comment: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: @Christina this is the source I've used...